# Is there a Salesforce Stack Exchange Developer Group in India?

Tags: discussion

I am a Salesforce Developer from Mumbai India.I have almost 2 years of Experience now in Salesforce and 4 years of Total Experience.

I heard about Salesforce Developer Meetup earlier.I would like to meet new people in order to maintain professional contact and aware about job openings .

If there is any online group from worldwide,I would like to join the same.

Thanks inn Advance!

Comment: You might what to check the [success community](https://success.salesforce.com/featuredGroups?filter=a0L3000000Rq7MvEAJ)

Comment: @glls thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check The meetup page where you will find all the related details.

https://www.meetup.com/pro/salesforcedevs

Also you can follow your local developer group for more updates.

There is one Meetup which you can surely attend.

https://www.meetup.com/Mumbai-Salesforce-Developer-Meetup/events/243985548/